# css text formatting issue on android default browser

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application which can be browsed on android mobiles.
I am facing following issue when zoom in and zoom out by double tap

There is a sentence in h3 tag, when I double tap to zoom in, text get wraped properly. But wen I zoom out by again doing double tap, text dose not reformat automatically.

css I am Using is:

```
 h3 {
    font-size: 1pc;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.375;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: `font-size: 1pc; font-size: 1.6rem;` why?

Comment: This is for the requirement, is it that these properties are causing problem?